# TypeScript oneliner to PHP

Tags: php, typescript, translate

I'm translating a code from TypeScript to PHP and that's going well so far.
In TypeScript there are some oneliners that I need to translate but I don't seem to get it right.

The TypeScript code is:

```
const InContent: string = subclass.Ins
        .map((In: In) => In.OutId + In.OutIndex)
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b, '');
```

Now I know that PHP 7 has functions like `array_map`, `array_reduce` and `array_column`.
I think it is possible to create this TypeScript oneliner also in PHP as a oneliner, but I can't see how.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You can start by reading the documentation pages of [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried some combinations but it doesn't give me the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code appears to add the `OutId` and `OutIndex` together (I can only assume it's a mathematical addition, and not a string concatenation), and then concatenate all those together into one string. So:

```
join(array_map(function ($in) { return $in->outId + $in->outIndex; }, $ins))
// I'm assuming `$in` is an object here
```

Even in JS that `reduce` would be more succinct as `map(...).join()`.

Comment: outId is a string and outIndex is a int in the TypeScrypt code.
Thank I will try this.

Comment: Code is not working for me.
`array_map` need the second parameter to be an array.

Comment: Well, `subclass.Ins` is also an array, and I have no idea what the equivalent in your PHP code is, so I've just put `$ins` here as a placeholder. You need to fill in the blanks.